# How to put heading in the center of an image

Tags: html, css

I want to put the heading in the center of the image I try to put image then heading then give the heading negative margin but when I did that the other element go up and make it  look bad

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="rose image "
    <h2>i want to put this heading in the center of the above image  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: set the image as a `background-image`

Comment: use position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
div {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg");
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>i want to put this heading in the center of the above image </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: @Downvoter Can you comment the reason for the down vote?

Comment: no, i want it as an image inside the div not in css

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```css
.image  {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
.image h2 {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 2;
   top: 50%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="rose image " />
    <h2>i want to put this heading in the center of the above image  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the `<h2>` and `position: relative` on the `div`.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dte7bat2g/image/upload/v1488492447/sample.jpg" alt="rose image" />
  <h2 class="child">i want to put this heading in the center of the above image </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: it doesn't work in my design I have a header
when I apply your code the heading goes up to the header
and also I want it the div either in the center now I can't put it in the center

Comment: Apply the css on specific classes and not on generic `div` and `h2`, otherwise other divs might inherit all the properties here.

Answer (score 0):

The other method is to use `flex` and `background-image`.

```css
.bg {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/200x200");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <h1> TEXT </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: i want it as image in html

Answer (score -1):

Like this?

```css
    h2{
   padding:20%;
 }
```

```html
<body background="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/N3BgXEI.jpg">
<div>
    <h2>I want to put this heading in the center of the above image  </h2>
</div>
</body>
```